# The sum of two subspaces

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ be two subspaces of V. Define the sum of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ to be the subset of V

$V_{1}+V_{2}=${$\overrightarrow v_{1} + \overrightarrow v_{2}:\overrightarrow v_{1} \in V_{1}, \overrightarrow v_{2} \in V_{2}$}

Prove that $V_{1}+V_{2}$ is a subspace of V.

$V_{1}+V_{2} \subset V$, then $\forall \overrightarrow  v_{1} \in V_{1}, \overrightarrow v_{2} \in V_{2}$, we have $\overrightarrow v_{1}+\overrightarrow v_{2} \in V$

Approach: $\forall  \overrightarrow v_{1}, \overrightarrow v_{3} \in V_{1}$ and $\forall \overrightarrow v_{2}, \overrightarrow v_{4} \in V_{2}$

$\overrightarrow v_{1}+ \overrightarrow v_{2}+ \overrightarrow v_{3}+ \overrightarrow v_{4}=( \overrightarrow v_{1}+ \overrightarrow v_{3})+( \overrightarrow v_{2}+ \overrightarrow v_{4})$

Since $ \overrightarrow v_{1}$ and $ \overrightarrow v_{3} \in V_{1}$ and $V_{1}$ is a subspace, $ \overrightarrow v_{1}+ \overrightarrow v_{3} \in V_{1}$

Same can be said for $ \overrightarrow v_{2}$ and $ \overrightarrow v_{4}$: $ \overrightarrow v_{2}+ \overrightarrow v_{4} \in V_{2}$

This implies $ \overrightarrow v_{1}+ \overrightarrow v_{2}+ \overrightarrow v_{3}+ \overrightarrow v_{4} \in V_{1}+V_{2}$

Is this approach correct? If so, should I only continue to prove scalar multiplication and non emptiness to finish the problem?

Comment: Yes, this looks good.

Comment: Yes.Always go back to the definitions. It is often the easiest way. Check that $V_1+V_2$ satisfies each of the requirements for being a vector subspace of $V$.